# How to solve package conflict on conda

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda

I want to use Conda to create a virtual environment from a YAML file.
However, many packages end up with a Conflict error.
The best way to solve this is to install each package individually instead of creating a virtual environment from a YAML file, right?
If anyone knows of a better way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conda-forge which has a strong dependency resolution implementation.

Newer conda versions (>=4.6) introduced a strict channel priority feature.
Type

```
conda config --describe channel_priority
```

for more information.

The solution is to add the conda-forge channel on top of defaults in your .condarc file when using conda-forge packages and activate the strict channel priority with:

```
$ conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

This will ensure that all the dependencies will come from the conda-forge channel unless they exist only on defaults.

You could also use Pipenv, and the Pipfile feature it comes with.
Pipenv will attempt to install sub-dependencies that satisfy all the requirements from your core dependencies.

see more:

https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not used to writing code, so here's a specific question: I want to install a package in this YAML file, but I'm experiencing a lot of conflicts. Can this also be handled by conda-forge?

https://github.com/ardigen/mol-cycle-gan/blob/master/environment.yml

Comment: I can imagine there can be a high number of conflicts due to the large number of packages and specific versions in the yaml specification. This is easier solved by Pipenv where you can soften the version restrictions for the minimal necessities.

Comment: Thank you for your early reply. I will look up Pipenv once and give it a try. If I can ask you any more questions, please let me know.

Comment: You are very welcome, and I hope everything works out.